# Which is a higher end model or are they equal: Radeon HD 5870 or GeForce GTS 360M

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

Are these comparable products?

**Radeon HD 5870** and **GeForce GTS 360M**

I am wondering because I am comparing these two products:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834114804

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834220695

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Radeon is a little better.

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/graphics-card-radeon-hd-5870-geforce-gtx-480,review-31892-6.html

Answer (score 1):

The Radion headline spec:

> ASUS G Series G73JH-X1 NoteBook Intel Core i7 720QM(1.60GHz) 17.3" **8GB** Memory **500GB** HDD 7200rpm DVD Super Multi ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5870

The GeForce headline spec:

> TOSHIBA Qosmio X505-Q875 NoteBook Intel Core i7 720QM(1.60GHz) 18.4" **6GB** Memory DDR3 1066 **320GB** HDD 7200rpm BD Combo NVIDIA GeForce GTS 360M

You're not comparing like with like.  The Asus has more memory and a larger hard-drive than the Toshiba so that might point to the graphics being lower spec. However, other components might well also account for the difference in price.

Both graphics cards have the same memory and the same display resolution so I would say that they're are much the same. Check out some reviews and performance stats of the two cards and see if they make the choice any easier.

Comment: I would go with the NVidia card if you use CUDA for movie playback , for converting or if you want to use Linux (NVidia got the best support for Linux). If you will only use it for gaming, then ATI is better. (well.. I wouldn't buy any of those laptops..)

Comment: My G73JH-A2 should be here in a couple of weeks.  You can't get a better machine for the money!  That said, I have a Toshiba that I adore.  I think you are good with either machine.

Answer (score 1):

Tom's Hardware has a very comprehensive charts section for comparing graphics cards:

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/charts/2010-gaming-graphics-charts-high-quality/benchmarks,101.html